# Select drop down with multiple checkboxes using handlebar

Tags: handlebars.js

I have written this code:

```
<select {{#if required}}required{{/if}} 
        {{#if multiple}}multiple{{/if}}
        class="{{blockName}}-select"
        name="{{selectId}}"
        id="{{selectId}}">
    {{#each options}}{{this}}{{/each}}
</select>
```

Unfortunately the select dropdown is not showing with a checkbox. Can you please help me?

Comment: Did you check whether all the variables you access exist and have a correct value?

Comment: Yes I have checked it, and values are coming in dropdown after call ({{element "filters"}} this code), but after using' <select class="select">
                        {{#each options}}{{element "filters"}}{{/each}}
                    </select>' No values dispay